# Trying to get information from a struct pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, structure, hook

I'm kind of new to C++ so beware! I'm hooking onto a function that requires the following structure.

```
typedef struct _RELYING_PARTY_TOKEN
{
   DWORD Reserved;
   DWORD Length;
   PBYTE pToken;
} RELYING_PARTY_TOKEN, *PRELYING_PARTY_TOKEN;
```

Here is the hook. pToken [out] is XML (SAML) but is outputted as PBYTE. I need to be able to steal this information and dump it, but I'm having trouble compiling my application due to the errors.

```
HRESULT AuthGetToken_hook(DWORD UserIndex, const CHAR *pUrn, DWORD UrnLength, RELYING_PARTY_TOKEN **pToken, XOVERLAPPED *pXOverlapped)
{
 HRESULT result = XAuthGetToken(UserIndex, pUrn, UrnLength, pToken, pXOverlapped);  

 printf("XAuth Url: %s\n", pUrn);
 return result;
}
```

Now I've tried a few methods to extract it such as;

```
 PBYTE token = *pToken->pToken;
```

but it does not allow me to compile and I get errors like so:

```
left of '->pToken' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
```

Comment: Why *pToken? I think it should be just pToken or use a dot instead of the arrow

Comment: I think you need to parenthesize `*pToken`.

Comment: @SatA I've tried this also because *PRELYING_PARTY_TOKEN is a pointer and the parameter requires **PRELYING_PARTY_TOKEN.

Comment: @Rufflewind Thank you is there anywhere I can read up on why this is required? It was a difficult question to Google.

Comment: "C operator precedence" will turn up lots of info, like this Wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence. `-> Element selection through pointer` has higher precedence than `* Indirection (dereference)`.

Comment: Because `*pToken->pToken` is interpreted as `*(pToken->pToken)`, which is probably not what you wanted.  There is also [this chart](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), which is basically equivalent to what Andrew Medico linked.